# Problem with counting total items in array

Tags: c++

I wanted to get a count of total items in the array. So, here's what I made.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int countIt(string arr[]){ //function which counts array and returns count
    int count = 0;
    while(arr[count] != "\0"){
        count++;
    };
    return count;
};
int main() {
    string vehicle[] = {"volvo","car"};//array to be counted
    cout<<countIt(vehicle);
    return 0;
};
```

the **output** is 6 instead of 2.

Why does it happen? Is it due to the wrong way of passing array of strings to function **countIt(string arr [])** or is it the wrong way of iterating over the array of strings ?

Comment: Well is there a `"\0"` in your array?

Comment: None of the strings are equal to `"\0"` so this is undefined behavior (out-of-bounds array access). Instead use `std::vector<std::string> vehicle;` and then you can just ask `vehicle.size()`.

Comment: Why 1 is expected instead of 2?

Comment: I suggest adding `cout << arr[count] << ' ' << count << endl;` to your while loop to see what's going on.

Comment: Why not simply using an `std::vector<std::string>` or `std::array<std::string, N>`, where N is the number of elements? Or the task is to implement such a bicycle?

Comment: @MikeCAT i expected 1 because car is the 0th element in the list and volvo is the first element. `vehicle[0]  = car; vehicle[1] = car;`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I will recommend you to use vectors

```
 vector<string> arr;
arr.push_back("volvo");
arr.push_back("car");
cout<<arr.size();
```

expected output is 2 
But in your question the expected output was 1 i assuming {car , volve} is one element for that you can use

```
vector<string,string> arr;
arr.push_back(std::make_pair("volvo","car"));

cout<<arr.size();
```

expected output : 1

Answer (score 0):

For fixed size arrays an expression like this can be used to obtain number of elements:

```
string vehicle[] = {"volvo","car"};
cout << (sizeof(vehicle)/sizeof(vehicle[0]));
```

but `sizeof` should be used in the same function or block in which `vehicle` is defined.

Comment: That's highly dependent on where the array is defined, compared to where you're using the `sizeof`. Should maybe clarify that in your answer.

Comment: but when we are passing `vehicle` to a function as a parameter it won't work

Comment: @NewtronMalayalam That's correct. The *only* way for a function to know the length is to pass it as a parameter too.